# Unable to Tether via USB 3.0

Tags: linux, usb, internet, android, tethering

I plug my cable into an USB 3.0 slot, then enable tethering, and I have the interface listed, but no actual connection—I get temporary-failure-in-name-resolution error when trying to ping anything:

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:2b:34:96:0c:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp2s0u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:6a:a2:21:34:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And here is what I have when my phone is connected via an USB 2.0 port (only interface name differs):

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:2b:34:96:0c:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s18f2u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:fd:99:2b:1d:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here is what *dmesg* shows after I unplug my cable off an USB 2.0 slot and then insert it into a 3.0 one:

```
[ 1024.836805] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1024.839044] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enp0s18f2u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:12.2-2, RNDIS device
[ 1024.894912] audit: type=1130 audit(1658489981.539:58): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 1027.140095] usb 8-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1027.263472] usb 8-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1027.370108] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN urb submitted to disabled ep
[ 1027.370119] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN urb submitted to disabled ep
[ 1027.370124] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN urb submitted to disabled ep
[ 1027.493475] usb 8-2: device descriptor read/64, error -2
[ 1027.723432] usb 8-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1027.869225] usb 8-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1027.869237] usb 8-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1027.869242] usb 8-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1027.869246] usb 8-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1027.869250] usb 8-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[ 1034.236902] usb 8-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1034.653424] usb 8-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1034.796137] usb 8-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1034.796148] usb 8-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1034.796153] usb 8-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1034.796157] usb 8-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1034.796161] usb 8-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[ 1034.801868] rndis_host 8-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:02:00.0-2, RNDIS device, a2:52:0d:24:48:2c
[ 1034.841206] rndis_host 8-2:1.0 enp2s0u2: renamed from usb0
```

And then back to 2.0 one:

```
[ 1368.903916] usb 8-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1368.904118] rndis_host 8-2:1.0 enp2s0u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:02:00.0-2, RNDIS device
[ 1372.179998] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1372.303316] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1372.557558] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1372.557570] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1372.557576] usb 1-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1372.557580] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1372.557583] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[ 1377.290696] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1377.689998] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1377.837516] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1377.837527] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1377.837532] usb 1-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1377.837536] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1377.837539] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[ 1377.840158] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:12.2-2, RNDIS device, 46:37:c6:dd:89:18
[ 1377.878982] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enp0s18f2u2: renamed from usb0
```

In fact, there is one more problem: after replugging the cable to any slot, no matter what version of USB it is, my connection speed drops down like hell: 1 mega**bit** per second or so. It lasts until I reboot the system.

Here is what *dmesg* shows about the USB port on the system boot:

```
[    1.005525] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.153435] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 2.23
[    1.153440] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.153443] usb 1-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[    1.153444] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[    1.153445] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
```

And here I enable tethering for the first time:

```
[   36.579734] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   36.996821] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   37.144352] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[   37.144356] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   37.144358] usb 1-2: Product: Nokia 2.2
[   37.144359] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[   37.144360] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[   37.419554] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   37.483531] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:12.2-2, RNDIS device, 9e:fd:13:0f:49:54
[   37.483618] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   37.496873] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enp0s18f2u2: renamed from usb0
```

---

Also, check [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1331768/usb-tethering-much-slower-than-wifi-tethering).

Comment: Which phone are you using for tethering? Some old Android versions do have issues with USB3.x ports (or have issues with special and at the time experimental "USB3.0" features enabled in the phone).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Nokia 2.2 on Android 11

Comment: Even worse... Many Nokia models have reported issues with tethering regardless of the Android version. I suggest taking some time to peruse the Nokia forums.